# Is it possible to ask Fortran to write out some results once the program is forced to stop?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am solving a fixed point problem through the following algorithm:

```
1. specify grids x1,x2,x3,... xn 
2. initial guess f=0 on all grids x1, x2, x3, ..., xn
3. update f according to some mapping T. f'=Tf on all grids.
4. calculate distance ||f'-f||. If greater than tolerance, go back to 3; otherwise, end. 
5. Write a .txt file to record the solution f.
```

If let'say, I'm interested in checking out f and f' before the tolerance is reached (i.e. before the program jumps from 4 to 5), is there a way to ask Fortran to write out f and f' once the program is forced to stop? Something like:

```
IF (stop message received) THEN
   PRINT  f and f' to files
END IF
```

I know a variation of doing that is to write f and f' each time the function is updated. But that's perhaps too costly as the algorithm takes 100 seconds for 1 iteration and about 200 iterations to finish, which is approx. 6~7 hours.

Any thoughts and suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: There is some useful discussion of related problems attached to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33619071).

Comment: clarify what you mean by "stop message"

Comment: come to think, if the iteration takes 100 seconds, simply writing every result isn't consequential is it?  (unless `n` is very large of course)

Comment: @agentp I mean `ctrl+c` in Ubuntu terminal for the stop message. `n` is 12000 in the current version, and there are 4 other variables that are written in the document with `f`. So 12000*5. You're perhaps right. this should not take more than several seconds for each iteration?

Comment: @francescalus Thanks for the link. The checkpoint sounds a good habit to pick up.

Answer (score 1):

So replace

```
4. calculate distance ||f'-f||. If greater than tolerance, go back to 3; otherwise, end. 
5. Write a .txt file to record the solution f.
```

with

```
4. calculate distance ||f'-f||. If greater than tolerance, go back to 3. 
5. Write a .txt file to record the solution f. end
```

This seems so obvious I expect I've completely missed the point.